# numpy multiplication based on combinations of a list

Tags: python, numpy

I have list of n numpy arrays and a list of corresonding names. An example:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
i = 3
x = [np.array(np.random.randint(-1,high=1, size=100)).T for k in range(i)]
names = ['n1', 'n2', 'n3']
```

Where `i` can be anything, but the length of the corresponding names are equal.

What i want is to find the possible combinations, such that:

```
import itertools
combinations = list(itertools.combinations(names,2))
new_names = ['*'.join(i) for i in combinations]
new_names
Out[]: ['n1*n2', 'n1*n3', 'n2*n3']

[[names.index(i) for i in [*combinations[k]]] for k in range(len(names))]
Out[]: [[0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 2]]
```

What is the easiest way to multiply the elements of x based on the combinations? So that output for this example is:

```
[x[0]*x[1], x[0]*x[2], x[1]*x[2]]
```

output:

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about simply using `combinations` as you did for the names?

```
from itertools import combinations
out = [a*b for a,b in combinations(x, 2)]
```

output:

```
[array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]),
 array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]),
 array([0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])]
```